# Multi-class regression in nolearn?

Tags: nolearn

I'm trying to build a Neural Network using nolearn that can do regression on multiple classes.

For example:

```
net = NeuralNet(layers=layers_s,
             input_shape=(None, 2048),
             l1_num_units=8000,
             l2_num_units=4000,
             l3_num_units=2000,
             l4_num_units=1000,
             d1_p = 0.25,
             d2_p = 0.25,
             d3_p = 0.25,
             d4_p = 0.1,
             output_num_units=noutput,
             output_nonlinearity=None,
             regression=True,
             objective_loss_function=lasagne.objectives.squared_error,
             update_learning_rate=theano.shared(float32(0.1)),
             update_momentum=theano.shared(float32(0.8)),
             on_epoch_finished=[
                    AdjustVariable('update_learning_rate', start=0.1, stop=0.001),
                    AdjustVariable('update_momentum', start=0.8, stop=0.999),
                    EarlyStopping(patience=200),
                                    ],
             verbose=1,
             max_epochs=1000)
```

noutput is the number of classes for which I want to do regression, if I set this to 1 everything works. When I use 26 (the number of classes here) as output_num_unit I get a Theano dimension error. (dimension mismatch in args to gemm (128,1000)x(1000,26)->(128,1))

The Y labels are continues variables, corresponding to a class. I tried to reshape the Y labels to (rows,classes) but this means I have to give a lot of the Y labels a value of 0  (because the value for that class is unknown). Is there any way to do this without setting some y_labels to 0?

Comment: What is your current  `y_train` shape?

Comment: y_train has the following shape: (1082,). All these are continues variables corresponding to different (26) classes.

Comment: Are you sure they are continuous, or do they take discrete values (0, 1, ..., 25)?

Comment: They are continuous so what I meant was; [Class, Value]: [A, 7.9], [B, 5.2] [A, 4.2] etc. So there are 26 different classes but 1082 continues values on which I want to do (multi class) regression.

Comment: So you want to ignore the class? I don't understand, could you include an example of expected output? And also the first few lines of `y`?

Comment: Correct, I have different target classes (data sources) with a lot of different  continues values, the number of classes should correspond to the num_output units, every output unit performs regression on one target. What I'm trying to do is very similair to joint DNN in this Article;(http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~gdahl/papers/deepQSARJChemInfModel2015.pdf).  So the first few lines of y look like this; 7.9, 5.2, 4.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multiclass (or multilabel) regression with 26 classes, your output must not have shape `(1082,)`, but `(1082, 26)`. In order to preprocess your output, you can use [`sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize.html)
which will transform your 1D output to 2D output.

Also, your output non linearity should be a softmax function, so that the rows of your output sum to 1.